# How to reuse a service in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have made a service to upload a file on server. its work perfectly, I am calling service like this,

```
Intent upload = new Intent(this, UploadFileService.class);
        upload.putExtra("File", o);
        upload.putExtra("UserName", username);
        upload.putExtra("Password", password);
        startService(upload);
```

and it starts uploading my one file, and now I want to upload second file simultaneously using the same service without disturbing first one.

right now it disturbs first uploading. please help me....

define in manifeast.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".UploadFileService"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</service>
```

Comment: Can you describe, or paste output showing, how the first upload is "interrupted"?  Sounds like your service needs to create/spawn some worker threads...